# how do i actually use the python-for-android modules?

Tags: android, python, kivy, pyserial

I'm trying to write a app for android with kivy. I've been using buildozer, and I can get the touchtracer demo to run on the android device.

So far it's been great, but now I'd like to try using pyserial to get access to the serial port. I've seen this page: https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/Modules , which has a built module for pyserial (and even bluetooth, that i'd like to use someday), but doesn't have instructions on how to use them.

Is it just a matter of copying the egg to a certain directory, and it automatically gets built into the final apk? If there are any examples of how to do this with buildozer, I will be greatly appreciative. Googling did not seem to turn up what I was looking for.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked is for a different python-for-android project, Kivy's is at https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.

In general, you can include any pure python module in your apk by simply adding it to the requirements line in buildozer, e.g. `requirements = pyserial,kivy`.

Modules that are not pure python can be included if there is a recipe available for compiling on android, you can see the available recipes at https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes . If a recipe exists, you simply add the module name to the requirements line as above and it will be used automatically. If no recipe exists then you have to write one, which isn't necessarily very hard.

I don't know anything about pyserial, but it looks like it's probably pure python so you just need to add it as above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (Sorry about the wrong link) I have a pure python lib, and I'm running buildozer from my virtualenv, but that lib is not getting picked up. Is the list of recipes from the link you gave the only recipes available? If I were to write my own for this python lib, would I just dump it in .buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android (which I found after trying to do a verbose build)? Thanks again, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you actually do what I said above? Adding it to the requirements line?

Comment: Ha, yup. Sorry if I'm sounding obtuse. The pyserial one is now working  (although you must comment termios from blacklist.txt accd to this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-android/VlcNlF6R4lE). My second python lib is installed from github into my virtualenv, but is not picked up from the requirements line. For the time being, I've just copied the module into my program directory, but had tried a recipe as well, with no results. I'll keep plugging away. Thanks again for your help!